# If a field $k$ is not algebraically closed, $k$ is not a $C_R$ field for any $0\le R<1$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm reading Dr. Pete Clark's paper *Around Chevalley-Warning Theorem* and I have a question about the proof of the following proposition on page 14:

Proposition: For a field $k$, the following are equivalent:
(i) $k$ is algebraically closed.

(ii)$k$ is $C_0.$

(iii) There is some $0\le R<1$, such that $k$ is $C_R$.

Recall the definition of $C_R$ property of a field $k$: $R\geq 0$, for $\forall$ $d,n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$, with $d^{R}<n$, $\forall f\in k[t_1,\cdots,t_n]$ homogeneous, $\deg f=d$ , $\exists$  $0\neq x \in k^n$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Specifically, I don't quite understand the part of the proof from $(iii)\implies (i)$. The proof goes as following: we prove it by contrapositive, so we assume first k is not algebraically closed. Let $l/k$ be a field extension of degree d. Choose a basis $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_d$ of $l/k$, and use this to identify $l$ with $k^{d}$, and view $\alpha \in l$ as giving a k-linear endomorphism of $k^{d}$ by multiplication. For indeterminates $t_1,\cdots,t_d$, let $p(t_1,\cdots,t_d)=det(\alpha_1 t_1+\cdots+ \alpha_d t_d)$. Thus P is a homogeneous polynomial of degree d with coefficients in k. Moreover, every nonzero $x\in k^{n}$ corresponds to a nonzero element of $l$, and since $l$ is a field, multiplication by $x$ has nonzero determinant. It follows that $P(x_1,\cdots,x_d)=0$ if and only if $x=0$. So whenever we have a degree d field extension , we have a degree d homogeneous polynomial in d variables which has only trivial solution, which means $k$ is not $C_R,_d$ for any $R<1$.

I'm not very familiar the concept of field extension but I have seen a few examples. I have the following questions regarding the proof:

1. I don't think I fully understand the meaning of the sentence: "view $\alpha \in l$ as giving a $k$-linear endomorphism of $k^{d}$ by multiplication." Does it mean we could multiply $\alpha$ with any element in $k^{d}$ and get a new element in $k^d$? Is it true that this endomorphism is an automorphism? Could anyone elaborate what this means?
2. How do you evaluate the determinant appeared in this equation: $p(t_1,\cdots,t_d)=det(\alpha_1 t_1+\cdots+ \alpha_d t_d)$? Isn't $\alpha_1 t_1+\cdots+ \alpha_d t_d$ a polynomial? How to calculate the determinant of a polynomial? Why $P$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$?

Thank you in advance for any feedback and advice!

Comment: For the first question, we're just talking about the map $k^d \rightarrow k^d$, $\beta \mapsto \beta \alpha$. It's clearly an endomorphism; the inverse is the map coming from multiplication by $\alpha^{-1}$.

Also, thanks for asking this question! I've been thinking about this sort of thing for a while and it's hard to find references. Hope you get a good answer!

Comment: For the second question, I'm thinking we're maybe really talking about the norm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to question 1: it's more clear now. But I'm still confused by the second question. Did you treat $a_1t_1+\cdots+ a_dt_d$ as a vector? If it refers to the norm, which norm do we use here?

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a concise and easy explanation. I think taking a look at Example 1.2.3 of Poonen's book "Rational Points on Varieties" might be enlightening though. It is also a good reference for material on $C_r$ fields. You can find it here: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf

Comment: @ Sam Streeter: thank you for the reference ! I believe the idea that $\det$ refers to the norm really makes sense now.